# Layover in Stansted for a non UE national

Tags: uk, transit, layovers

I am a non UE national and have a resident card in France.

I am in Budapest right now and have found a ticket from Budapest to Paris with a Layover in London Stansted airport.
The first flight goes to terminal 1 and the second departs from terminal 2B.
Do you think that i can take it since i'm not leaving the airport ? or i'm gonna need a transit visa if so ?

Thank you very much

Comment: not really because it's dated of 2017

Comment: The question cited is from 2017, but the UK Guidance cited in the answer remains valid. Unlike many other airports, Stanstead airport has no "transit" area. All passengers arriving at Stansted on flights from non-UK airports must pass through UK immigration.